# Passing details to an iframe using GET statement

Tags: php, mysql

On a page I have a list of communities...On click community I send the variable over to the nextpage.I can display various details on the item using Get statement.

i.e:

`communityname =$_GET['communityname']` in my sql statement. The problem am having is displaying comments related to that comments on an iframe on the same page.I tried using the same sql 
`GET (communityname =$_GET['communityname']` in the recordset but it seems its not getting any passed variable.

Comment: Show some code please...

Comment: Am using recordset Dusan Radojevic

Comment: I can pass the variables to showpage.php from the listpage.php when you click on a community listed  but i have an iframe in showpage.php and i want the iframe to get the variables also but its not working

Comment: How do you pass the variables to the iframe?

Comment: @Alex using the same GET communityname =$_GET['communityname'] i used on the showpage..

Comment: you need to pass that variable to iframe src also...

Comment: okay thank you Dusan but how please this is my iframe src http://localhost/Yheeps/Community/updates.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass that variable to iframe src also...

So src of iframe should be

```
<iframe src="localhost/Yheeps/Community/updates.php?communityname=<?php print $_REQUEST['communityname']; ?>"></iframe>
```

**Edit:** I have changed src to fit your needs... I think that this would be enough for you to solve it. But if you show some more code I could be more precise.

Comment: thank you but its not working...

Comment: Paste some more code of problematic page please...

Comment: <iframe src="http://localhost/Yheeps/Community/updates.php?communityname=<?php print $_REQUEST['communityname']; ?> name="content" width="600" height="1200" frameborder="0" id="content3"></iframe>...That's the iframe

Comment: Everything looks ok on the iframe, is it rendering anything inside iframe when you load page this way? If yes, you to get that variable on updates.php also so that you can process it... I am here to help just give me more info.

Comment: yeah thank you very much..No its not..What code do you need..Please tell me

Comment: @Dusan....i hope you know am using a recordset

Comment: Edit your main question with both page on which you are displaying iframe and the iframe page also...